# Model is Huge when imported to gltf-viewer

Tags: gltf

When I import my glb export to [gltf-viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) it gets enormous.
It looks fine in [babylon.js viewer](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) or [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/).

It might be helpful to mention that the model was exported from [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/).

you can find the glb file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zA0bo9WmZF_l1fJapJgBsa2FrncYxw4I/view?usp=sharing).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The scale is not applied to the armature. You can check it in the side panel (key N) and apply it with Ctrl+A, Scale. *But* if you do that, the animation becomes wonky. Not sure how to fix this...

Comment: The model itself is OK. This is a [viewport scaling bug in that particular viewer](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/issues/147). Applying scale to the armature can work around the issue as mentioned above.

Comment: Yes applying the scale is the solution but it messes the animation as mentioned

Comment: @RezaLavasuny did you find a workaround? I’m trying to do the same thing with a Mixamo FBX but am having the same problem.

Comment: @KDP Yes, It's a bug as Don McCurdy Mentioned. Update to 3.3 to fix the problem.

Comment: @RezaLavasuny I'm running 3.3.1. If I apply scale to EVERYTHING, the mesh disappears from view. Alternatively, if I only apply scale to the mesh, the armature is still set to 0.01, and the GLTF gives me results that look too large. Any ideas about a workaround? It would save me hours of failed attempts!

Comment: Can you send the file?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug as Don McCurdy mentioned. Updating to 3.3 fixed the problem for me.